# Split string by words

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, numpy

I've got a list of sentences where each sentence split on words.
I mean, `sentences` looks like here:

```
[['word0', 'word1'], ['word2', 'word3', 'word4', 'word5'], 
 ['word6', 'word7', 'word8'], ....]
```

Each sentence have some length, so I find `max_sentence_len` like

```
max_sentence_len=max(max_sentence_len, len(current_sentence))
```

I want to have a matrix and array. Let's take some sentence `['word2, 'word3', 'word4', 'word5']` :

```
'word2'  ---> 'word3'
'word2' 'word3'  ---> 'word4'
'word2' 'word3' 'word4' ---> 'word5'
```

So in matrix it will be:

```
matrix[0, 0] = 'word2' ---> array[0] = 'word3'
matrix[1 0] = 'word2', matrix[1 1] = 'word3' ---> array[1] = 'word4'
....
```

An do it for all sentences!

So first of all I count how many lines will be in matrix:

```
summ = 0
for line in sentences:
    summ += len(line)-1
```

Than I do matrix and array as explained:

```
train_x = np.zeros([summ, max_sentence_len], dtype=np.int32)
train_y = np.zeros([summ], dtype=np.int32)

ind = 0
for sentence in sentences:
    for i in range(len(sentence)-1):
        for j in range(i+1):
            train_x[ind, j] = word2idx(sentence[j])
        train_y[ind] = word2idx(sentence[i+1])
        ind += 1

print('train_x shape:', train_x.shape)
print('train_y shape:', train_y.shape)
```

Where `word2idx` just give index of word in vocabulary.

It works good! But too long (if `summ`, for example, more `630000`)

**Is it any way to do this faster?**

**UPD:**
For better understanding let's look at sample case. Let us have follow sentences: "The pencil is red", "They are strange", "No legacy is so rich as honesty". Is this way my `sentences` will be:

```
[['the', 'pencil', 'is', 'red'], 
 ['they', 'are', 'strange'],
 ['no', 'legacy', 'is', 'so', 'rich', 'as', 'honesty']]
```

Next (create matrix and array) :

```
train_x --> train_y:
the --> pencil
the pencil --> is
the pencil is --> red
they --> are
the are --> strange
no --> legacy 
no legacy --> is
no legacy is --> so
no legacy is so --> rich
no legacy is so rich --> as
no legacy is so rich as --> honesty
```

So summarizing  `train_x` will be:

```
max_sentence_len = 7

[ [the 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [the pencil 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [the pencil is 0 0 0 0] 
  [they 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [they are 0 0 0 0 0]
  [no 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [no legacy 0 0 0 0 0]
  [no legacy is 0 0 0 0]
  [no legacy is so 0 0 0]
  [no legacy is so rich 0 0]
  [no legacy is so rich as 0] ]
```

`train_y`:
     `[pencil, is, red, are, strange, legacy, is, so, rich, as, honesty ]`

Of course not exactly words in matrix and array - they indexes in vocabulary (`word2idx`)
Create vocabulary can be simple like:

```
vocab = []
for sentence in sentences:
    for word in sentence:
        if word not in vocab:
            vocab.append(word)
```

and `word2idx` simple like:

```
def word2idx(word)
    return vocab.index(word)
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't completely understand what it is you are trying to do. I understand your input is `sentences` - what is the expected output. Can you provide the expected output for a sample case?

Comment: @Mortz I've updated my question with example. I think now you're understand exactly what I do. If no for some reasons - you can write code as in example and check yourself

Comment: @J.Doe that's not how it works, lol! You take the trouble to formulate the problem clearly, we formulate a clear answer. Start by replacing your horrible list `vocab` with a set; looking up things in a long list is a huge bottleneck. I bet that's taking up the bulk of your time, since you have to look up every damn word.